# Can I convert stored procedure join result by SQLQuery into a form of EF ORM?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I need to convert the result of a SQL stored procedure into EF ORM.

The stored procedure contains a query like this :

```
select * 
from TbA
join TbB on TbA.aId = TbB.aId`
```

It works, but in ORM mode, the contents of TbB doesn't appear in the object that is returned. I must use this query as a stored procedure in my project.

C# code:

```
var result = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TbA>("sp_1");
```

EF entity class :

```
[Table("TbA")]
public partial class TbA
{
    public TbA()
    {
        TbB = new HashSet<TbB>();
    }

    [Key]
    public long aId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string rNo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TbB> TbB { get; set; }
}

public partial class TbB
{
    [Key]
    public long rowId { get; set; }

    public long aId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string kKey { get; set; }

    public virtual TbA TbA { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You tell EF to create `TbA` objects from the query and that's what it does. It simply discards the `TbB` data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go with any of this two options

**First**, Create a class that contains both attributes from TbA and TbB since you are using join. The class will contain the attributes you which to return.

**Second** Use LINQ queries example.

```
var queryResult = from tba in dbContext.TbA
    join tbb in database.TbB on tba.aId equals tbb.aId
    select new {
        //construct your class here as dynamic objects
        TbA.attr1 = tba.attr1,
        Tbb.attr1 = tbb.attr1
        // and so on
    }
```

`queryResult` will assume any class selected in the select statement.

Also if you want to use the class created with option 1, the select section of the query changes to

```
select new TbAandTbB{
    attr1 = tba.attr1,
    attr2 = tbb.attr1
    // and so on
}
```

Comment: No, I should use this query as a stored procedure.

Comment: Then use the First option by creating a class that will accept all parameters you need from TbA and TbB and map it to the stored procedure

Comment: The first option is not applicable, I want to have an object of TbA which includes a list of TbB (a List<TbB> may contain a lot of records).It seems I'm forced to use two queries for this scenario.